# Without expanding, how to prove that

Tags: matrices, determinant

Without expanding, how to prove that

$$\begin{vmatrix} bc & ab & a \\ ac & b^2 & b \\ b & c & 1 \end{vmatrix} = (a+b) \begin{vmatrix} 1 & b & 1 \\ a & b^2 & b \\ b & c^2 & c \end{vmatrix} ?$$

I've tried to sum the rows or columns but no progress.

Comment: If substitute $a=-1, b=1, c=0$, then LHS=$-2$, RHS=$0$. Perhaps, task is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed, the exercise is mistaken, and it is not even easy to guess how it should have been stated correctly. Now that you know the answer, better delete this question, to avoid downvotes or closure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is clearly mistaken.

Comment: It seems that correct task is: prove that $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}bc & ab & a \\ ac & b^2 & b \\ b & c & 1 \end{array}\right| = (a+b)\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & b & 1 \\ a & b^2 & b \\ b & c^2 & c\end{array}\right|.$$

Comment: Then steps of proof: add $2$nd row to $1$st row: $$\left|\begin{array}{ccc}bc & ab & a \\ ac & b^2 & b \\ b & c & 1 \end{array}\right| = \left|\begin{array}{ccc} (a+b)c & (a+b)b & (a+b) \\ ac & b^2 & b \\ b & c & 1\end{array}\right|.(a+b)\left|\begin{array}{ccc} c & b & 1 \\ ac & b^2 & b \\ b & c & 1\end{array}\right|;$$ multiply $3$rd row by $c$ and divide $1$st column by $c$: $$... = (a+b)\left|\begin{array}{ccc} c/c & b & 1 \\ ac/c & b^2 & b \\ b\cdot c/c & c\cdot c & 1\cdot c\end{array}\right| = (a+b)\left|\begin{array}{ccc} 1 & b & 1 \\ a & b^2 & b \\ b & c^2 & c\end{array}\right|.$$

Answer (score 1):

On the left hand side, we have$\begin{vmatrix}
bc & ab & 1 \\ ac & b^2 & b \\ b & c & a 
\end{vmatrix}
= bc \begin{vmatrix} b^2 & b \\ c & a \end{vmatrix} -ab \begin{vmatrix} ac & b \\ b & a \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} ac & b^2 \\ b & c \end{vmatrix} = bc(ab^2-bc)-ab(a^2c-b^2) + (ac^2-b^3) = ab^3c-b^2c^2-a^3bc+ab^3+ac^2-b^3.$

On the right hand side, we have
$(a+b)\begin{vmatrix} 1 & b & 1 \\ a & b^2 & b \\ b & c^2 & c \end{vmatrix} = (a+b)\left( \begin{vmatrix} b^2 & b \\ c^2 & c \end{vmatrix} -b \begin{vmatrix} a & b \\ b & c \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} a & b^2 \\ b & c^2 \end{vmatrix} \right)= (a+b)((b^2c-bc^2)-b(ac-b^2)+(ac^2-b^3)) = (a+b)(b^2c-bc^2-bac+b^3+ac^2-b^3) = -a^2bc+a^2c^2+b^3c-b^2c^2.$

This leads me to believe the problem is stated incorrectly.